# waitfor delay is good for batch update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, synchronization, sql-update

I am writing number of update queries in batch as a transaction. For example,

```
Begin transaction
BEGIN TRY 
update x
.......

update y
......

update x join y
......

update x join z
.......

COMMIT;

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK;
END CATCH
```

x,y and z table have millions of records.

I want to know are they going to execute sequentially or do i have to add WAITFOR DELAY in between each update?
I am new so please help me. How i can make sure that each update should run.
EDIT:
One more thing when I am running this batch file against 1 billion records, its getting suspended I have seen from **dm_exec_requests** table. Why its showing suspend and how I can overcome with it.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no need to put 'WAITFORDELAY' as it is going to run sequentially.
2. Also regarding SUSPENDED in the sense that is being halted due to lack of resources. This is common in terms of execution(s). I can suggest you like use smaller transactions rather than having one huge transaction.

Thanks.